# Hibernate JPA stored procedure call?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I am using Hibernate JPA. I have below Oracle Stored procedure.

```
CREATEORREPLACEPROCEDURE PROC_AB
(
      in_name VARCHAR2,
      in_lastname VARCHAR2,
      out_emp_id OUTINTEGER
)
```

How can I invoke this stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507418/how-can-i-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-has-one-out-parameter-as-sysrefcurs):

1. First you define the stored procedure named native query:

   ```
   @javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "call_proc_ab", query = "{ call PROC_AB(:cmpid,:status,?) }", resultClass = Long.class, hints = {
   @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
   ```
2. Then you execute it using:

   ```
   TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("call_proc_ab", Long.class); 
   query.setParameter("cmpid",cmpid); 
   query.setParameter("status",status); 
   Long empId = query.getSingleResult();
   ```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. where should I place stored procedure named native query? I mean in XML file?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591524/using-a-named-native-sql-query-using-xml-mapping-error)